# How to increase data_pump directory size in Oracle RDS instance

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to import a data dump from S3 bucket to Oracle RDS instance following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html).

However my dump is around 10GB in size & when I try to download it from S3 bucket to data_pump_directory using below procedure, it gives below error.

```
SELECT rdsadmin.rdsadmin_s3_tasks.download_from_s3(
      p_bucket_name    =>  '<bucket_name>', 
      p_directory_name =>  'DATA_PUMP_DIR') 
   AS TASK_ID FROM DUAL;
```

Error: Insufficient disk space to download, at least 10724474880 bytes required

My current data_pump_directory size is 4GB.
Want to know how to increase it. I tried increasing the storage of RDS & upgrading the DB class, but no luck.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can take the easy route and increase the storage size.
[AWS->Documentation->Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS)->User Guide->
Increasing DB instance storage capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html#USER_PIOPS.ModifyingExisting)

But there is another option.

1. .Make export data `expdp` with the option `filesize = 2GB`
2. Copy file one by one and import, delete dump file and repeat several
   times.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your RDS Oracle instance use more storage than expected, by default all tablespaces created should have auto-extend = true, the DATA_DUMP_DIR simply use the same storage as the data files, which means if you increase the storage size of the RDS instance should fix the issue.
Please have a look at this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-oracle-storage-optimization/, to check how much storage is allocated for each tablespace and how to clean up the DATA_DUMP_DIR if needed.

AWS RDS also got the feature of "storage autoscaling", you can try to enable that as well by following this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html#USER_PIOPS.Autoscaling